# Change preference screen's preference item title text color and align left

Tags: android, preference, preferencefragment, android-text-color

For some reason the sign-out `Button` is being pushed right. How to resolve this? Anything I do in the custom layout's `TextView` and `LinearLayout` does not work. I just want to change this preference item's color

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/coral"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/title_sign_out"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And i use the layout here

```
   <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/title_section">

        <Preference android:key="@string/key_account" />

        <Preference
            android:key="@string/key_logout_btn"
            android:widgetLayout="@layout/pref_account_text" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
```

You can see the screenshot below.

[preference layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHfIu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out finally.
When i tried with layout attribute, it wasn't showing anything because i had `android:id="@android:id/title"` set in the custom layout's textview.

So removing `android:id="@android:id/title"` and setting the preference custom layout to android:**layout**="@layout/pref_account_text" instead of **widgetLayout** resolved it